# The number of ways to divide 5 people into three groups

Tags: combinatorics

> How many ways can 5 people be divided into three teams where each team must have at least one member?

Assumably they can either be put in one group of 3 people then two groups with 1 person, or two groups with 2 people then one group of 1 person.
Hence my answer was $$ ^5C_3 +\, (^5C_2)  \cdot (^3C_2)$$
However the provided answer was 
$$ ^5C_3 +\, (^5C_2)  \cdot (^3C_2) \cdot (1/2)$$
Where did the **1/2** come from?

Thanks.

Comment: Because  the groupings $(A),(BC),(DE)$ and $(A),(DE),(BC)$ are the same (for example).

Comment: Is there a way of knowing how many will be repeated without listing them out?

Comment: Sure, there's a symmetry.  the two $2-$member teams can be interchanged.  You have the same problem with the other term, though you short-circuited it.  You could have written the first term as $\binom 53\times \binom 21 \times \binom 11$ but then you'd have had to divide by $2$ again to cancel the symmetry between the $1-$ member teams.

Comment: Thanks, but how can you tell the amount of symmetry there is?

Comment: Not following.  the symmetry is that every pair of $2$ member teams is counted twice (switching the order).  There are situations in which this can get tricky...for example, in counting rolls of a pair of dice you have to distinguish the cases in which you get two of a kind.  But there is no problem here.

Comment: If there were 7 people, would the number of ways they could be put into two groups of 3 and one group of 1 be: $^7C_3 \times ^4C_3 \times (1/2)$ ?

Comment: Yes!  But try a more subtle example.  Suppose you divide your $7$ into four teams.  Then we can have three groups of $2$ and one singleton.  Now what is the symmetry?

Comment: Is that answer 3? In which case are there $^7C_2 \times ^5C_2 \times ^3C_2 \times (1/3)$ combinations?

Comment: No.  Three objects can be permuted in $6$ ways, hence you have to divide by $6$.  In general, $n$ objects can be permuted in $n!$ ways.

Comment: I think I get it now. So would the number of ways to divide 8 people into two groups of 3 and one group of 2 be $^8C_3 \times ^5C_3 \times  \times (1/2)$ since $^8C_3 \times ^5C_3$ on its own will mean each $\{A, B,C\}, \{D, E, F\}$ pair will appear 2! times?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 3):

Two add-ons to the information already given.

> - The factor $\frac{1}{2!}$ occurs in fact *twice* in your example, since we have
>     \begin{align*}
>   &(^5C_3) (^2C_\color{blue}{1})(^1C_{\color{blue}{1}})\color{blue}{\frac{1}{2!}}
>   +\, (^5C_\color{blue}{2})(^3C_\color{blue}{2})(^1C_1)\color{blue}{\frac{1}{2!}}\\
>   &\quad=10\cdot2\cdot1\cdot\frac{1}{2}+10\cdot 3\cdot 1\cdot \frac{1}{2}+\\
>   &\quad=25
>   \end{align*}
> - We can reformulate the problem and ask for the number of ways to *partition* a set consisting of $5$ elements into $3$ non-empty subsets. These numbers are known as *[Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind)* ${n\brace k}$.
>
>   Here we are looking for
>     \begin{align*}
>   {5\brace 3}=25
>   \end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

When you pick the team as two players, another two, and then just the final one is left over, consider the following: if the five players are named $A, B, C, D, E$, then you might start by picking the duo $\{A, B\}$ and then $\{C, D\}$, which results in the breakdown of $\{\{A, B\}, \{C, D\}, \{E\}\}$ **or** you might have first picked the duo $\{C, D\}$ and *then* picked $\{A, B\}$, which would result in the same grouping of $\{\{A, B\}, \{C, D\}, \{E\}\}$.

To avoid this double-counting, you divide in this scenario by $2$. (Or, equivalently, multiply by $1/2$.)

Comment: Thanks, but how do I tell how much repeat-counting I've done without listing out the combinations?

Comment: @CasperC. Yes, this is the difficult part of combinatorics. You may wish to return to the definition of, e.g., $^5 C_3$ to see how and **why** it was defined; its definition, too, involves a bit of division to avoid overcounting, and the scenario here involves a similar bit of reasoning.

Comment: May I rephase that? How do we know there are *only* two repetitions of $\{\{A, B\}, \{C, D\}, \{E\}\}$ ? How would we know how many repetitions of groups there would be if there were 7 people instead of 5?  Thanks for helping.

Comment: @CasperC. This relies on the observation that $n$ objects can be arranged in $n!$ ways. Here, you have the $2$ groups overcounting by a factor of $2! = 2$.